# That sky going to hold? Could you explain this sentence for me?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

[image]

I was watching the movie called ‘Flight.’
In the movie scene, the fight attendant said to a pilot as soon as the pilot land on the plain, and said like ‘that sky gonna hold?’ 
I had searched on google and I don’t know the meaning.
Could you explain for me this sentence?

Comment: It probably means the **weather**. Is that weather going to stay the same, or will it change?

Comment: lands the plane, is not "land on the plain". It means will the clouds in the sky produce rain or not. "That sky" would mean a sky filled with clouds. [Can you explain it to me.= explain **something to someone**, make a note :)]